# How to enter hour and minute with shiny components in python?

Tags: python, r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I have a shiny based dashboard. I take the dates with "ui.input_date" component from users in shiny. How can i take the hour and minute info with shiny components? When I check the [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/py/api/reference/shiny.ui.input_text_area.html), the only component I could find was "ui.input_text_area". Is there any specific component for taking hour and minute info?

[image]

Comment: I don't think there currently is a time input option for Shiny for Python. You could use two drop downs (select inputs) instead, if you don't want to use free text?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about it but 1-min freq dropdown list does not seem proper to me. Thanks for your answer!